# Android, ListView IllegalStateException: "The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification"

Tags: android, exception, listview, adapter

**What I want to do**: run a background thread which calculates ListView contents and update ListView partially, while results are calculated.

**What I know I have to avoid**: I cannot mess with ListAdapter contents from background thread, so I inherited AsyncTask and publish result (add entries to adapter) from onProgressUpdate. My Adapter uses ArrayList of result objects, all operations on those arraylists are synchronized.

**Research of other people**: there is very valuable data [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/82685). I also suffered from almost daily crashes for group of ~500 users, and when I added `list.setVisibility(GONE)/trackList.setVisibility(VISIBLE)` block in onProgressUpdate, crashes lowered by a factor of 10 but not disappeared. (it was suggested in [answer](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/android-developers@googlegroups.com/2010-04/msg01174.html) )

**What I got sometimes**: please notice, it happens really rarely (once a week for one of 3.5k users). But I'd like to get rid of this bug completely. Here is partial stacktrace:

```
`java.lang.IllegalStateException:` The content of the adapter has changed but ListView  did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131296334, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.transportoid.Tracks.TrackListAdapter)]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1432)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2062)
at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3234)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
[...]
```

**Help?** Not needed anymore, see below

**FINAL ANSWER:** As it turned out, I was calling `notifyDataSetChanged` every 5 insertions to avoid flickering and sudden list changes. It cannot be done such way, always notify adapter when base list changes. This bug it long gone for me now.

Comment: Did you call notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Of course, in onProgressUpdate there goes sequence: list.setVisibility(GONE) - addObjectToList/synchronized operation on list/ - notifyDataSetChanged() - list.setVisibility(VISIBLE)    (and without visibility modifications exception happens far more often)

Comment: Are you modifying the underlying ArrayList on a different thread? All changes, even to the ArrayList that is referenced by the Adapter, have to occur on the UI thread.

Comment: @Qberticus - as I clearly stated, I do not modify ArrayList from different thread, but from method onProgressUpdate of AcyncTask - it works in GUI thread.

Comment: You said you access the ArrayList via synchronized methods. That's different then only modifying it on the UI thread.

Comment: @Qbeticus - I know, synchronization was added just for sure, all list operations are intended to be applied from UI thread. But somehow it still fails. I don't want to remove live list updating completely, but currently I'm unable to prevent occasional force closes...

Comment: @tomash i got same exception i am using pull to refresh and in on post execute i have written **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   lvAutherlist.completeRefreshing();** but sometimes got this error how to solve it

Comment: i had the same problem. finally i got the solution

before updating listview, if the soft keypad is present close it first. after that set data source and call notifydatasetchanged().

while closing keypad internally listview will update its ui. it keep calling till closing keypad. that time if data source change it willl throw this exception.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I was adding items to my `ArrayList` outside the UI thread.

Solution: I have done both, `adding the items` and called `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the UI thread.

Comment: I both added the items and called notifyDataSetChanged() in the UI thread and I resolved this.

Comment: Genial comment, really.

Comment: This is a Multithreading Issue and Using Properly Synchronized Blocks This can be prevented. Without putting extra things on UI Thread and causing loss of responsiveness of app.Check my answer below.

Comment: For future readers - doing calculations in background thread is a good thing, but you should pass results to UI thread and do the adding items to adapter base collection and notifying adapter in the same block of code.

Comment: I don't think your issue is the only possibility. I would suggest go to ListView.java source code and search for IllegalStateException.

Comment: I thought `ArrayList` is a non UI object?

Comment: @Mullins Can u please show a sample for your solution?I'm stuck at the same issue

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem, but I fixed it using the method

```
requestLayout();
```

from the class `ListView`

Comment: when should we call this method?

Comment: @DeBuGGeR after you either add items to the ListView or change the adapter of it.

Comment: what if i am adding elements in asynctask

Comment: Just for the record, @Dr.aNdRO, you collect your results in AsyncTask. doInBackground() and save your results to update the list in AsyncTask.onPostExecute(), which will run in the UI thread. If you *need* to update as you go, use AsyncTask.publishProgress() and AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate() which also runs in the UI thread.

Answer (score 23):

This is a **MultiThreading** Issue and Using Properly **Synchronized** Blocks This can be prevented.
Without putting extra things on UI Thread and causing loss of responsiveness of app.

I also faced the same. And as the most accepted answer suggests making change to adapter data from UI Thread can solve the issue. That will work but is a quick and easy solution but not the best one.

As you can see for a normal case. Updating data adapter from background thread and calling notifyDataSetChanged in UI thread works.

This illegalStateException arises when a ui thread is updating the view and another background thread changes the data again. That moment causes this issue.

So if you will synchronize all the code which is changing the adapter data and making notifydatasetchange call. This issue should be gone. As gone for me and i am still updating the data from background thread.

Here is my case specific code for others to refer.

My loader on the main screen loads the phone book contacts into my data sources in the background.

```
    @Override
    public Void loadInBackground() {
        Log.v(TAG, "Init loadings contacts");
        synchronized (SingleTonProvider.getInstance()) {
            PhoneBookManager.preparePhoneBookContacts(getContext());
        }
    }
```

This PhoneBookManager.getPhoneBookContacts reads contact from phonebook and fills them in the hashmaps. Which is directly usable for List Adapters to draw list.

There is a button on my screen. That opens a activity where these phone numbers are listed.
If i directly setAdapter over the list before the previous thread finishes its work which is fast naviagtion case happens less often. It pops up the exception .Which is title of this SO question. So i have to do something like this in the second activity.

My loader in the second activity waits for first thread to complete. Till it shows a progress bar. Check the loadInBackground of both the loaders.

Then it creates the adapter and deliver it to the activity where on ui thread i call setAdapter.

That solved my issue.

This code is a snippet only. You need to change it to compile well for you.

```
@Override
public Loader<PhoneBookContactAdapter> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    return new PhoneBookContactLoader(this);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<PhoneBookContactAdapter> arg0, PhoneBookContactAdapter arg1) {
    contactList.setAdapter(adapter = arg1);
}

/*
 * AsyncLoader to load phonebook and notify the list once done.
 */
private static class PhoneBookContactLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<PhoneBookContactAdapter> {

    private PhoneBookContactAdapter adapter;

    public PhoneBookContactLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public PhoneBookContactAdapter loadInBackground() {
        synchronized (SingleTonProvider.getInstance()) {
            return adapter = new PhoneBookContactAdapter(getContext());    
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry how did you do that? How did you syncronized the Background thread code and the notifydatasetchange call? I am using a doInBackground when filtering data on an AutocompleteTextView and I am facing the same problem...Could you advise me something in order to resolve?

Comment: @user3019105 - Synchronizing two background threads. one which updates the data in background and other which notifies the ui thread to setAdadpter or notifydatasetchanged using handler.post methods or runOnUiThread methods available. For my particular case I synchronized two loaders with their doInBackground synchronized on a singleton object. One start preparing data on the splash screen itself to be quickly available for the dashboard screen. That was my need.

Comment: Could you please post a snippet of code of this implementation? In my case, I have resolved calling clear() on the adapter, creating a temporary ArrayList<T> of filtered objects, then making a call to the addAll(tmpArrayList) and finally the notifyDataSetChanged(). I make all this calls inside the publishResult() Filter method, running on the main thread. Do you think this is a reliable solution?

Comment: @user3019105 check the edited answer. Hope its helpful to you now

Comment: this answer requires a lots of reading on why it works, http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html is a good place to start

Answer (score 16):

I solved this by have 2 Lists.  One list I use for only the adapter, and I do all data changes/updates on the other list.  This allows me to do updates on one list in a background thread, and then update the "adapter" list in the main/UI thread:

```
List<> data = new ArrayList<>();
List<> adapterData = new ArrayList();

...
adapter = new Adapter(adapterData);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

// Whenever data needs to be updated, it can be done in a separate thread
void updateDataAsync()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // Make updates the "data" list.
            ...

            // Update your adapter.
            refreshList();
        }
    }).start();
}

void refreshList()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            adapterData.clear();
            adapterData.addAll(data);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.invalidateViews();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I wrote this code and had it run in a 2.1 emulator image for ~12 hours and did not get the IllegalStateException. I'm going to give the android framework the benefit of the doubt on this one and say that it is most likely an error in your code. I hope this helps. Maybe you can adapt it to your list and data.

```
public class ListViewStressTest extends ListActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView list;
    AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> task;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        this.list = this.getListView();

        this.list.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        this.task = new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {
            Random r = new Random();
            int[] delete;
            volatile boolean scroll = false;

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                if(scroll) {
                    scroll = false;
                    doScroll();
                    return;
                }

                if(values == null) {
                    doDelete();
                    return;
                }

                doUpdate(values);

                if(ListViewStressTest.this.adapter.getCount() > 5000) {
                    ListViewStressTest.this.adapter.clear();
                }
            }

            private void doScroll() {
                if(ListViewStressTest.this.adapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                int n = r.nextInt(ListViewStressTest.this.adapter.getCount());
                ListViewStressTest.this.list.setSelection(n);
            }

            private void doDelete() {
                int[] d;
                synchronized(this) {
                    d = this.delete;
                }
                if(d == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for(int i = 0 ; i < d.length ; i++) {
                    int index = d[i];
                    if(index >= 0 && index < ListViewStressTest.this.adapter.getCount()) {
                        ListViewStressTest.this.adapter.remove(ListViewStressTest.this.adapter.getItem(index));
                    }
                }
            }

            private void doUpdate(String... values) {
                for(int i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++) {
                    ListViewStressTest.this.adapter.add(values[i]);
                }
            }

            private void updateList() {
                int number = r.nextInt(30) + 1;
                String[] strings = new String[number];

                for(int i = 0 ; i < number ; i++) {
                    strings[i] = Long.toString(r.nextLong());
                }

                this.publishProgress(strings);
            }

            private void deleteFromList() {
                int number = r.nextInt(20) + 1;
                int[] toDelete = new int[number];

                for(int i = 0 ; i < number ; i++) {
                    int num = ListViewStressTest.this.adapter.getCount();
                    if(num < 2) {
                        break;
                    }
                    toDelete[i] = r.nextInt(num);
                }

                synchronized(this) {
                    this.delete = toDelete;
                }

                this.publishProgress(null);
            }

            private void scrollSomewhere() {
                this.scroll = true;
                this.publishProgress(null);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                while(true) {
                    int what = r.nextInt(3);

                    switch(what) {
                        case 0:
                            updateList();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            deleteFromList();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            scrollSomewhere();
                            break;
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(0);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        };

        this.task.execute(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your work! I noticed that for ArrayAdapter method hasStableIds()=false; my implementation returned true which was not quite right, as rows were sorted before every notifyDataSetChanged(). I'll give it a try - if crashes survives, I will continue investigation. Best regards!

Answer (score 5):

Several days ago I met the same problem and causes several thousands of crash per day, about 0.1% of users meet this situation. I tried `setVisibility(GONE/VISIBLE)` and `requestLayout()`, but crash count only decreases a little.

And I finally solved it. Nothing with `setVisibility(GONE/VISIBLE)`. Nothing with `requestLayout()`.

Finally I found the reason is I used a `Handler` to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after update data, which may lead to a sort of:

1. Updates data to a model object(I call it a DataSource)
2. User touches listview(which may call `checkForTap()`/`onTouchEvent()` and finally calls `layoutChildren()` )
3. Adapter gets data from model object and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and update views

And I made another mistake that in `getCount()`, `getItem()` and `getView()`, I directly use fields in DataSource, rather than copy them to the adapter. So finally it crashes when:

1. Adapter updates data which last response gives
2. When next response back, DataSource updates data, which causes item count change
3. User touches listview, which may be a tap or a move or flip
4. `getCount()` and `getView()` is called, and listview finds data is not consistent, and throws exceptions like `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but...`. Another common exception is an `IndexOutOfBoundException` if you use header/footer in `ListView`.

So solution is easy, I just copy data to adapter from my DataSource when my Handler triggers adapter to get data and calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. The crash now never happens again.

Comment: This was my issue.  In my case the getCount() was returning the new count available before notifyDataSetChanged was called.  Since my list was 'virtual', I now capture the updated count in my notifyDataSetChanged method and then return this cached count when asked for the count via getCount().

Answer (score 4):

Had this happen intermittently, turns out I only had this issue when the list was scrolled after a 'load more' last item was clicked. If the list wasn't scrolled, everything worked fine.

After MUCH debugging, it was a bug on my part, but an inconsistency in the Android code also.

When the validation happens, this code is executed in ListView

```
        } else if (mItemCount != mAdapter.getCount()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The content of the adapter has changed but "
                    + "ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of "
```

But when onChange happens it fires this code in AdapterView (parent of ListView)

```
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        mDataChanged = true;
        mOldItemCount = mItemCount;
        mItemCount = getAdapter().getCount();
```

***Notice the way the Adapter is NOT guaranteed to be the Same!***

In my case, since it was a 'LoadMoreAdapter' I was returning the WrappedAdapter in the getAdapter call (for access to the underlying objects). This resulted in the counts being different due to the extra 'Load More' item and the Exception being thrown.

I only did this because the docs make it seem like it's ok to do

ListView.getAdapter javadoc

> Returns the adapter currently in use in this ListView. The returned
>   adapter might not be the same adapter passed to
>   setAdapter(ListAdapter) but might be a WrapperListAdapter.

Comment: I am having a similar issue . Can you please suggest how to fix it.

Comment: If you look at the 2 code samples above you'll see mAdapter in ListView and getAdapter() in a parent of ListView (AdapterView). If you override getAdapter(), the result of getAdapter() may not be the mAdapter. If the counts of the 2 Adapters are different, you get the error.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was related to the use of a **[Filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html)** together with the ListView.

When setting or updating the underlying data model of the ListView, I was doing something like this:

```
public void updateUnderlyingContacts(List<Contact> newContacts, String filter)
{
    this.allContacts = newContacts;
    this.filteredContacts = newContacts;
    getFilter().filter(filter);
}
```

Calling `filter()` in the last line will (and must) cause `notifyDataSetChanged()` to be called in the Filter's `publishResults()` method. This may work okay sometimes, specially in my fast Nexus 5. But in reality, it's hiding a bug that you will notice with slower devices or in resource intensive conditions.

The problem is that the filtering is done asynchronously, and thus between the end of the `filter()` statement and the call to `publishResults()`, both in the UI thread, some other UI thread code may execute and change the content of the adapter.

The actual fix is easy, just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` also before requesting the filtering to be performed:

```
public void updateUnderlyingContacts(List<Contact> newContacts, String filter)
{
    this.allContacts = newContacts;
    this.filteredContacts = newContacts;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // Fix
    getFilter().filter(filter);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a List if Feed objects.
It's appended and truncated from none-UI thread.
It works fine with adapter below.
I call `FeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in UI thread anyway but little bit later.
I do like this because my Feed objects stay in memory in Local Service even when UI is dead.

```
public class FeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int size = 0;
    private final List<Feed> objects;

    public FeedAdapter(Activity context, List<Feed> objects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
        size = objects.size();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        size = objects.size();

        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        try {
            return objects.get(position);
        } catch (Error e) {
            return Feed.emptyFeed;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even I faced the same problem in my XMPP notification application, receivers message needs to be added back to list view (implemented with `ArrayList`). When I tried to add the receiver content through `MessageListener` (separate thread), application quits with above error. I solved this by adding the content to my `arraylist` & `setListviewadapater` through `runOnUiThread` method which is part of Activity class. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm was facing the same problem with exactly the same error log.
In my case `onProgress()` of the AsyncTask adds the values to the adapter using `mAdapter.add(newEntry)`. To avoid the UI becoming less responsive I set `mAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false)` and call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` 4 times the second. Once per second the array is sorted.

This work well and looks very addictive, but unfortunately it is possible to crash it by touching the shown list items often enough.

**But it seems I have found an acceptable workaround.**
My guess it that even if you just work on the ui thread the adapter does not accept many changes to it's data without calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, because of this I created a queue that is storing all the new items until the mentioned 300ms are over. If this moment is reached I add all the stored items in one shot and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
Until now I was **not able to crash the list anymore**.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in Android  4 to 4.4(KitKat) and is resolved in  ">4.4"

See here:   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71936

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it. My problem was that I was using a `listview`, with an array adapter and with filter. On the method `performFiltering` I was messing with the array that have the data and it was the problem since this method is not running on the UI thread and EVENTUALLY it raises some problems.

Answer (score 1):

One cause for this crash is that `ArrayList` object cannot change completely.
So, when I remove an item, I have to do this:

```
mList.clear();
mList.addAll(newDataList);
```

This fixed the crash for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I called the method `GetFilter()` on an adapter from the `TextWatcher()` method on main Activity, and I added the data with a For loop on `GetFilter()`.
The solution was change the For loop to `AfterTextChanged()` sub method on main Activity and delete the call to `GetFilter()`

Comment: Please clarify your solution. I`m also in situation looks like u/

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, here's how I solved in my case. I verify if the `task` already is `RUNNING` or `FINISHED` because an task can run only once. Below you will see a partial and adapted code from my solution.

```
public class MyActivity... {
    private MyTask task;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // your code
       task = new MyTask();
       setList();
    }

    private void setList() {
    if (task != null)
        if (task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)){
            task.cancel(true);
            task = new MyTask();
            task.execute();         
        } else if (task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)) {
            task = new MyTask();
            task.execute();
        } else 
            task.execute();
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Item, Void>{
       List<Item> Itens;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {

        //your code

        list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapterItem= new MyListAdapter(MyActivity.this, R.layout.item, new ArrayList<Item>());
        list.setAdapter(adapterItem);

        adapterItem.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Itens = getItens();
        for (Item item : Itens) {
            publishProgress(item );
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Item ... item ) {           
        adapterItem.add(item[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //your code
        adapterItem.notifyDataSetChanged();     
        list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work or is better than the existing solutions. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please try one of these solutions :

1. Sometimes, if you add new object to data list in a thread (or `doInBackground` method), this error will occur. The solution is : create a temporary list and do adding data to this list in thread(or `doInBackground`), then do copying all data from temporary list to the list of adapter in UI thread (or `onPostExcute`)
2. Make sure all UI updates are called in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

i haved same problem when add new data in lazy image loader 
i just put

```
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in

```
       protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
         }
```

hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mullins said "
I both added the items and called `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the UI thread and I resolved this. –  Mullins".

In my case I have `asynctask` and I called `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `doInBackground()` method and the problem is solved, when I called from `onPostExecute()` I received the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had a custom `ListAdapter` and was calling `super.notifyDataSetChanged()` at the beginning and not the end of the method

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    recalculate();
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting exact same error and using AsyncTask :

```
`java.lang.IllegalStateException:` The content of the adapter has changed but ListView  did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131296334, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter... etc
```

I solved it by putting`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` at the bottom of my UI thread, that is my AsyncTask onPostExecute method. Like this :

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

 all my other stuff etc...
    all my other stuff etc...

           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            });
        }
```

Now my app works.

**EDIT : In fact, my app still crashed about every 1 in 10 times, giving the same error.**

Eventually I came across `runOnUiThread` on a previous post, which I thought could be useful. So I put it in my doInBackground method, like this :

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() { etc... etc...
```

And I removed the  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` method. Now, my app never crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same sittuation , I had many buttongroup insite my item on listview and I was changing some boolean values inside my item like holder.rbVar.setOnclik...

my problem occured because I was calling a method inside getView(); and was saving an object inside sharepreference, so I had same error above

How I solved it; I removed my method inside getView() to notifyDataSetInvalidated() and problem gone

```
   @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        saveCurrentTalebeOnShare(currentTalebe);
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. finally i got the solution

before updating listview, if the soft keypad is present close it first. after that set data source and call notifydatasetchanged().

while closing keypad internally listview will update its ui. it keep calling till closing keypad. that time if data source change it willl throw this exception.
if data is updating in onActivityResult, there is a chance for same error.

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                refreshList();
            }
        },100L);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1) create a `temp ArrayList`.

2) do your heavy works (sqlite row fetch , ...) in `doInBackground` method and add items to the temp arraylist.

3) add all items from temp araylist to your listview's arraylist in `onPostExecute` method.

`note:` you may want to delete some items from listview and also delete from sqlite database and maybe delete some files related to items from sdcard , just remove items from database and remove their related files and add them to temp arraylist in `background thread`. then in `UI thread` delete items existing in temp arraylist from the listview's arraylist.

Hope this helps.