# Can we have runOnUiThread in doInBackground()

Tags: java, android

```
@
Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String...params) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
```

The problem is when AysncTask executed and onPostExecute() get called (where `mAllResultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`; get called), `the Adapter has not bound to ListView yet`. I get the below exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034153, class
>   android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class
>   com....tracebuzz.allresults.AllResultsAdapter)]

the problem is the `ArrayList` that bound to my `Adapter` is changed in the Background thread.

[The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification - With AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771017/the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed-but-listview-did-not-receive-a-notificati)

The above problem is my exact situation, but i am just not sure how to apply in my case where there are such `10 ArrayList` getting modified in Back Ground Thread and `10 Adapaters` which needs to be notified.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the adapter data in a background thread, only in the UI thread. The background thread should create a local variable list, and on onPostExecute, or by runOnUiThread, copy the list to the adapter's list and call notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0):

Just move notifyDataSetChanged to the onPostExecute method of your async task. This method runs on the UI thread after doInBackground is complete. That way you can download and update your adapter content in the background and just refresh the actual view on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be able to run code on ui Thread in an AsyncTask.

If you doesn't have access to the context, than use

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(youRunnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue. I tried so many things, including runOnUiThread, but I think the best solution was to create a temporal ArrayList in the AsyncTask to fill it in doInBackground(). Then, you can both flush all these elements into the real ArrayList and notify the adapter in the onPostExecute() method (which runs on the UI thread).