# onScroll gets called when I set listView.onScrollListener(this), but without any touch

Tags: android, android-listview, onscroll

When I set the `onScrollListener` for my `ListView`, it calls `onScroll`. This causes a crash because certain things haven't been initialized.

Is this normal? Note: this is happening without me even touching the phone.

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnScrollListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    lv.setOnScrollListener(this);
    ...
}
...
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){
    if( firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount ){
        pullContactList();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is something wrong . oncreate is the first method which is called from an activity

Comment: my bad, it actually gets called when onCreate calls setOnScrollListner. is this normal?

Comment: what hasn't been initialized? The stuff in pullContactList()?

Comment: Yes. And also my adapter. I know I can call setonscrolllistner at the end of my oncreate. Or use a variable in onscroll to skip over its contents on the first call to it. But these are all patches. Is there a way to force setonscrolllistner to not call onscroll? Do I need to over ride the constructor?

Comment: Best one http://stackoverflow.com/a/6357973/1318946

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's normal because the source code for `setOnScrollListener` in `AbsListView` (the superclass of `ListView`) does this:

```
 public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener l) {
        mOnScrollListener = l;
        invokeOnItemScrollListener();
    }
```

and `invokeOnItemScrollListener` does this:

```
/**
     * Notify our scroll listener (if there is one) of a change in scroll state
*/
    void invokeOnItemScrollListener() {
        if (mFastScroller != null) {
            mFastScroller.onScroll(this, mFirstPosition, getChildCount(), mItemCount);
        }
        if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
            mOnScrollListener.onScroll(this, mFirstPosition, getChildCount(), mItemCount);
        }
        onScrollChanged(0, 0, 0, 0); // dummy values, View's implementation does not use these.
    }
```

depending on what it is you're trying to do, there are a number of ways to avoid this problem.

EDIT:

Since you only want to do this if the user actually scrolled, I suppose you could do something like:

```
    lv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    if(view == lv && motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {
                      userScrolled = true;
    }
return false;
                }
            });
```

Then..

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){
        if(userScrolled && firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount ){
            pullContactList();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I just want onScroll to not get called that first time, I want it to get called only when the user scrolls. Thanks. (i do realize I can move setonscrolllistner to later in the code, but I want to learn how to how to do it the other way)

Comment: for completeness: you forgot a return statement in your onTouch listener

Comment: I can't believe that behavior isn't mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Does it cause battery leakage? I mean is it normal?

Comment: The [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18385460/1276636) is simple and correct. No idea why the OP selected this one.

Comment: thumbsup for mentioning what android is doing at the back when setting the onScrollListener

Answer (score 59):

Just a reminder, according to the javadoc of

> MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL **:**
>
> This action is always delivered to the window or view under the pointer, which may not be the window or view currently touched.
>
> This action is not a touch event so it is delivered to onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent) rather than onTouchEvent(MotionEvent).

Hence, `motionEvent.getAction()` will never gets the SCROLL event. Check for MOVE will do the job

You can also do the similar thing in the `onScrollStateChanged` method of the `OnScrollListener`

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if(scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
            userScrolled = true;
        }   
}
```

Comment: hi sometime the method `onScrollStateChanged()` be not invoke,example when invoke method `adapter.notificationDataSetChange()`,it will be skip this method and into method `onScrollStateChanged()`.so this method is not suitably

Comment: I know this an old answer, but I just stumbled upon this issue myself. I understand why it's happening as I read the sourcecode for the `AbsListView`, but I don't understand why it should happen. Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: If you edit your answer such that it is a standalone answer I will accept it as best answer. Currently it seems to be an appendix to the other top answer.

Answer (score 3):

I use this solution and it works fine for me :

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                canScroll = false;
            } else if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING ||
                    scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                canScroll = true;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked solution for me!!! combination of above answer i made the solution!!
thanks to @LuxuryMode and @CrazyGreenHand

**My TouchListener:**
since MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL not trigged i used MOVE action

```
 expandableListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(view == expandableListView && motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                userScrolled = true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**My Scroll Listener:**

```
  expandableListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (firstVisibleItem == 0){
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
            }else {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
            }
            int lastVisibleItem = absListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
            if (userScrolled&&!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                onLoadMore();
                isLoading = true;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onScroll: firstVisibleItem=>"+firstVisibleItem+"==>visibleItemCount=>"+visibleItemCount+"==>totalItemCount==>"+totalItemCount+"==>lastVisibleItem==>"+lastVisibleItem);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the needful task only when visibleItemCount > 0;

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){
    if (visibleItemCount > 0 ){
        //perform the task to be done
    }
}
```