# Error when loading AmazingListView with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I am getting the error below when selecting an item in my  [AmazingListView](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/) . I am loading the data thru an AsyncTask (inBackround()) and calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() every 20 items that are loaded and the method onPostExecute. The list loads without any issues and when I select an item after the list is loaded I have no issues...I only get this error when I select item during the list loading. There is an issue opened in AmzingListView [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/issues/detail?id=3) but both solutions didnt help me. Any ideas would be appricated.

Error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034170, class com.foound.widget.AmazingListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
```

Code:

```
private ArrayList<object> list;


private class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, object, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

                    list = populatList();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls)
    {
                   Log.i("CallLogActivity", "CallLog is Loading");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                {

                    String str = getString();
                    boolean bool = getBoolean();
                    Object c = new Object(str,bool);
                    publishProgress(c);
                }

        //Doing Work Here!!

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(object... object)
    {           
        count++
                    updatelist(object);
        if (adapter != null)
        {
            if (count > 20)
            {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        super.onProgressUpdate(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you change the content of the adapter in your "doing work" code? (as I noteice your postExecute is `Void`)

Comment: yes I change the content of the adapter during "doing work" I see its being updated all the time. Problem is when I select item in list.

Comment: Have you checked whether the error message isn't telling the truth all along- as a first step, put the parts of your code that change the adapter in a runOnUIThread(Runnable...). (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: Sorry. Correction. I am not changing the content of the adapter in the doInBackground(). Can the error be false? How can I check? I am changing content of adapter in onProgressUpdate().

Comment: May I ask why you need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` then in postExecute?

Comment: just in case at the end of the loading data the count is smaller then 20 in the onProgressUpdate().

Comment: But if `count` has got nothing to do with the adapter, why do you need to call `notifyAdapterSetChanged`? I'm trying to get to the bottom of how the adapter is changed; knowing this code, there's no likely this error could throw without the adapter having been changed- by this, I include any object or data structure that is referenced from your `getView`, `getCount` or similar methods.

Comment: What is publishprogress(c)? Your doing something in the background thread - doInBackgrund() - that you're not supposed to. Post the code for this method please.

Comment: @Rarw agreed. This is probably quite simple to solve, but we just need to establish a few things first. Are you sure that you're not doing anything like I've said above from a background thread? Best.

Comment: I mean you can't be 100% sure. If you were you wouldn't be getting this error and asking us for help lol. There's not enough info up there to figure this out. Sorry.

Comment: I update code. I am only going thru an arraylist and getting info from my db and sending to onProgressUpdate() to update the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my issue was calling  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); only after 20 changes. I need to  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after every change....found it   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed)

Comment: I'm glad you worked out your problem. But you see, you *were* changing the content of the adpater! This error message doesn't lie here.