# AsyncTask java.lang.IllegalStateException ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)

Tags: android, listview, exception, adapter

Why do I get this result when I run my AsyncTask? 
What I do?
Before running AsyncTask I create new temporary LinkedHashMap and set its content from LinkedHashMap with original content
I get results as HTTP Response and then add results to my temporary LinkedHashMap
After running AsyncTask in onPostExecute I set temporary LinkedHashMap's content as content for my original LinkedHashMap and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on my adapter

```
FATAL EXCEPTION
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131099702, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class devz.tim.vk.helpers.WallAdapter)]
       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForTap.run(AbsListView.java:3300)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Here is my AsyncTask code:

```
public class LoadWall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public int[] OWNER_ID;
    public int OFFSET;
    public int COUNT;
    public boolean REFRESH;
    public Context context;
    public Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<String> LINKS = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> LIST;
    public WallAdapter ADAPTER;
    public ListView LISTVIEW;
    JSONObject obj;
    public ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> tempList;

    public LoadWall(int[] OWNER_ID, int OFFSET, int COUNT, boolean REFRESH,
            Context context, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> LIST,
            WallAdapter ADAPTER, ListView LISTVIEW) {
        this.OWNER_ID = OWNER_ID;
        this.OFFSET = OFFSET;
        this.COUNT = COUNT;
        this.REFRESH = REFRESH;
        this.context = context;
        this.LIST = LIST;
        this.ADAPTER = ADAPTER;
        this.LISTVIEW = LISTVIEW;
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        activity.setProgressBarVisibility(true);
        if (REFRESH == true){
            LIST.clear();
            if(tempList != null){
                tempList.clear();
            }
            LISTVIEW.requestLayout();
            ADAPTER.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        AppHelper.refreshAttacher.setRefreshing(true);
        tempList = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
        tempList = LIST;
    };

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            LINK = "here is link for json";
            obj = Helpers.getJson(LINK);
            if (obj != null) {
                Helpers.refreshListView(obj, tempList);
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(obj==null){
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.loadfailed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        LIST = tempList;
        ADAPTER.notifyDataSetChanged();
        activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        activity.setProgressBarVisibility(false);
        AppHelper.refreshAttacher.setRefreshComplete();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    };
}
```

I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed), but didn't get any result:

Comment: what is `Helpers.refreshListView(obj, tempList);`? did this work with UI?

Comment: How can I check this? This code just adds LinkedHashMap items to ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> tempList.