# IllegalStateException in Android listview

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

I used https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh  for pull to refresh in my listview

this is the code..........
in AsyncTask onPostExecute I wrote this one

```
adapter=new ServicesTypeTranDetailAdapter(getActivity(), items_list_trandetails);
servicesList.onRefreshComplete();
servicesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I was doing same functionality I didn't get any error. If am I kept the device idle for two hours then I got this error. Please help me. Thanks in advance...

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165659, class com.isp.activities.PullToRefreshListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1538)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchModeChanged(AbsListView.java:2977)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnTouchModeChanged(ViewTreeObserver.java:606)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.ensureTouchModeLocally(ViewRootImpl.java:2761)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.ensureTouchMode(ViewRootImpl.java:2745)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2872)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Share your stack tace and code

Comment: this link will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed

Comment: servicesList.onRefreshComplete(); servicesList.setAdapter(adapter); i think you should setAdapter first and refresh later not sure though

Comment: earlier I did setAdapter first and refresh later but at that time also I got the error

Comment: try adding adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I also tried this one but even also I am getting this error while my device is idle for 2hours. And also tried this  one also getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {

Comment: I added My stack trace. And also I tried with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
But this error happens only while kept my device idle for more than 2 hours