# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification - List with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter, universal-image-loader

I am trying to update a fragment with list view once the Async call is complete but I am getting the following error :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.

I am updating the adapter onPostExecute and have also checked the function is running on main thread but still I am getting the IllegalStateException.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        if (null != mClient)
            mClient.close();
        //TODO
            //Constants.IMAGES = result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
        Constants.IMAGES.addAll(result);
            Log.i("IMAGES", IMAGES.toString());
            if (mTheListener != null && firstCallFlag ) {
                firstCallFlag = false;
                mTheListener.GotoNextScreen();
            }else{
                dataUpdateListener.dataUpdated(result);
            }
    }

@Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if(afterTag != null){
            URL += "?after="+afterTag;
            System.out.println("::New URL:: "+ URL);
        }
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
        JSONResponseHandler responseHandler = new JSONResponseHandler();
        try {
            return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


@Override
public void dataUpdated(List<String> data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("::Notify data update listener called");
    System.out.println("Looper "+Looper.myLooper());
    System.out.println("Main Looper "+Looper.getMainLooper());
    imageUrls.addAll(data);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

//Fragment onCreateView - Adapter is set here

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_image_list, container,
            false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    // Adding the load more

    // LoadMore button
    Button btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");

    // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
    listView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

    /**
     * Listening to Load More button click event
     * */
    btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Starting a new async task
            Constants.getUrlFromRedditService();
        }
    });
    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            startImagePagerActivity(position);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

P.S: I am using Universal Image Loader to populate images on the list .

Comment: check this - http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/2013/11/16/fixing-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed-but-listview-did-not-receive-a-notification/

Comment: please post your `doInBackground()` method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, ListView IllegalStateException: "The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed)

Comment: Edited with doInBackground code

Comment: show the code block of where you setting the adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing the below line of code

```
 ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
```

with

```
 ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

See that for the listView you are always setting a new adapter and in your onPostExecute you are notifying to a different instance of adapter

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes all it takes is an extra pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was some problem with `getView()` function in your adapter,when to instance a `convertView`,you should provide arguments Content,you'd better use your 
`ActivityName.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`;

Comment: Its not related with any `Context`. Data is not getting update in `UI` thread that cause a problem.