# Fetching Record from Local Database and Showing in Listview IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, android, database, android-arrayadapter

Getting ids from one table and matching with another table and getting record from that table.Some time i get records in list but when i want to insert one more record in list illegalexception that is not notified to listview etc.

```
private void getAllRecords() {

    String cmpId = "";
 //fetching ids from this table one by one and passing id to another table
    Cursor preAppointmentRecord = JasperDatabase.getInstance(PreAppointmentsActivity.this).getPreAppointmentRecord();
    preAppointmentRecord.moveToFirst();
    if (preAppointmentRecord.getCount() != 0) {
        while (!preAppointmentRecord.isAfterLast()) {
            cmpId = preAppointmentRecord.getString(1);
            getAllCompanyName(cmpId);
            preAppointmentRecord.moveToNext();
        }

        preAppointmentRecord.close();

    }
}
private void getAllCompanyName(String companyId) {
    //fetching company names with matched ids
    Cursor companyNameCursor =    JasperDatabase.getInstance(PreAppointmentsActivity.this).getPreAppointmentCompanies(companyId);
    companyNameCursor.moveToFirst();
    if (companyNameCursor.getCount() != 0) {
        while (!companyNameCursor.isAfterLast()) {
//getting second string from database                
recordsAr.add(new PreAppointmentRecord(companyNameCursor.getString(2)));
            companyNameCursor.moveToNext();
        }
        companyNameCursor.close();
    }
}
```

AsyncTask class for calling to getAllRecords() function :

```
 protected Void doInBackground(String[] paramArrayOfString) {
        getAllRecords();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void paramVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(paramVoid);
        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
   //Notifying to listview for changing view
            customRecordsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**Customer adapter:**

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final int k = 0 ;
       //Using for getting all record storing in recordArray
        final PreAppointmentRecord preRecord = recordsAr.get(i);
```

**Logcat** :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.jmd.jasper, PID: 11265
                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131558625, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.jmd.jasper.activities.PreAppointmentsActivity$CustomRecordsAdapter)]
                                                                at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1566)
                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2564)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15601)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4881)
                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15601)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4881)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15601)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4881)
                                                                at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15601)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4881)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15601)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4881)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15601)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4881)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
```

Customer Adapter :

```
    private class CustomRecordsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return recordsAr.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            final int k = 0 ;

            final PreAppointmentRecord preRecord = recordsAr.get(i);
//            final PreAppointmentCustomer1 preRecord1 = recordsAr1.get(k);


            view = View.inflate(PreAppointmentsActivity.this, R.layout.custom_record_list_preappointment, null);
            TextView companyNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.companyNameTextView);


            companyNameTextView.setText(preRecord.CompanyName);
    //            nameTextView.setText(preRecord1.CustomerId);
     return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: add log info to find what actually going wrong

Comment: i have added the logcat so see below

Comment: add your activity and custom adapter complete code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed

Comment: I think you haven't updated the list that you send for adapter after getting the list in doInBackground. First update the list in adapter and then notify the adapter. This question doesn't deserve for any up votes though..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I fixed it using the method

***`requestLayout();`***

from the class ListView

Edit

```
myListView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: where to set this and how