# I am refreshing listview in every 30 seconds . click of list item error of notifydatasetchanged

Tags: android, listview, refresh, notifydatasetchanged

Here is my code:

```
    package com.saba.admin.w2track;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    import Adapters.VehicleListAdapter;
    import Model.UserData;
    import Model.VehicleData;

    public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        static ArrayList<VehicleData> vehicleArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        static  ArrayList<VehicleData> vehicleArrayList1=new ArrayList<>();
        boolean clearflag=false;
        static  ArrayList<VehicleData> vehicleArrayListMoving=new ArrayList<>();
        static ArrayList<VehicleData> vehicleArrayListStopped=new ArrayList<>();
        static ArrayList<VehicleData> vehicleArrayListActive=new ArrayList<>();
        static ArrayList<VehicleData> vehicleArrayListInActive=new ArrayList<>();
        String acctype;
      //static  VehicleListAdapter listAdapter;
        UserData userData;
        TextView txtStopped,txtMoving,txtTotal,txtInactive,txtAlerts;
        RelativeLayout moving,alerts,inactive,stopped,total;
        boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard3);
            setView();
            getBundleData();
          //  String acc[]={acctype};
            updateVehicles();
        }
            public void updateVehicles() {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DashboardActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                vehicle v = new vehicle();
                                v.execute(acctype);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 30000);
        }


        public void setView(){
            txtStopped=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtstopped);
            txtMoving=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmoving);
            txtAlerts=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtalerts);
            txtInactive=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtinactive);
            txtTotal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttotal);
            moving=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutMoving);
            stopped=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutStopped);
            alerts=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutAlerts);
            inactive=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutInActive);
            total=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutTotal);

        }

       public void getBundleData(){
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (b != null && b.containsKey("userData"))
            {
                userData=b.getParcelable("userData");
                acctype=b.getString("acctype");
                // Log.d("accountid",userData.getAccountId()+" ");
                Log.d("userid123..",userData.getUserId()+" ");
                Log.d("timediff123..",userData.getTimediff()+" ");
                //Log.d("km1..",userData.getMilesPerKms()+" ");
            }
        }
```

//vehicle asyncclass in dashboard..which is called in dashboard every 30 sec to get updated data & store in arraylist.

```
        private class vehicle extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

            private ProgressDialog dialog;
            String response="";
            private JSONObject res;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                try {
                                if(!DashboardActivity.this.isFinishing()) {

                        dialog = new ProgressDialog(DashboardActivity.this);
                        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
                        dialog.setCancelable(false);
                        // searchBox.setEnabled(false);
                        dialog.show();
                    }

    if(true) {
        vehicleArrayList.clear();
        vehicleArrayList1.clear();
        vehicleArrayListMoving.clear();
        vehicleArrayListStopped.clear();
        vehicleArrayListActive.clear();
        vehicleArrayListInActive.clear();
        Log.d("cleared1111", "cleared ");
        clearflag=true;
    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("eroror1111", e.toString() + " ");
    //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {



                    JSONObject vehicle_json = new JSONObject();

                    vehicle_json.put("pAccountId", userData.getUserId());


                    res = CustomHttpClient.postJsonObject("http://"+params[0]+".w2track.com/api/index.php?cmd=vehicles", vehicle_json,DashboardActivity.this);


                    String resData=res.getString("ResponseData");
                    JSONArray array=new JSONArray(resData);
                    Log.d("1111",array.length()+" ");
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                        Log.d("11112","2222");
                        VehicleData vehicleData=new VehicleData();
                        JSONObject jsonVehicleObj=new JSONObject(array.get(i).toString());
                        Log.d("111123", "2222");
                        if(jsonVehicleObj.getString("vehiclenumber").equals("null") ||jsonVehicleObj.getString("vehiclenumber")==null ){
                            Log.d("111124","2222");
                            continue;
                            // Log.d("11112","2222");
                        }
                        vehicleData.setVehicleNumber(jsonVehicleObj.getString("vehiclenumber"));
                        vehicleData.setPlacename(jsonVehicleObj.getString("location"));
                        vehicleData.setSpeed(jsonVehicleObj.getString("speed"));
                        vehicleData.setLandmark(jsonVehicleObj.getString("landmark"));
                        vehicleData.setIsActive(jsonVehicleObj.getBoolean("isactive"));
                        vehicleData.setVehicleType(jsonVehicleObj.getString("vehicletype"));
                        vehicleData.setFuel(jsonVehicleObj.getString("fuel"));
                        Log.d("fuel11115", vehicleData.getFuel() + " ");
                        vehicleData.setDept(jsonVehicleObj.getString("department"));
                        vehicleData.setDivision(jsonVehicleObj.getString("division"));
                        vehicleData.setIginition(jsonVehicleObj.getString("ignition"));
                        vehicleData.setLati(jsonVehicleObj.getString("lat"));
                        vehicleData.setLongi(jsonVehicleObj.getString("lng"));
                        vehicleData.setOdometer(jsonVehicleObj.getString("odometer"));
                        vehicleData.setGpsmode(jsonVehicleObj.getString("gpsmode"));
                        vehicleData.setInnerbattery(jsonVehicleObj.getDouble("inbatt"));
                        vehicleData.setExtbattery(jsonVehicleObj.getDouble("extbatt"));
                        vehicleData.setUnitId(jsonVehicleObj.getString("unitid"));
                        vehicleData.setUnitNo(jsonVehicleObj.getString("unitno"));
                        vehicleData.setIgnitionTime(jsonVehicleObj.getString("ign_time"));
                        vehicleData.setDate1(jsonVehicleObj.getString("date"));
                        vehicleData.setIconImage(jsonVehicleObj.getString("icon"));
                        vehicleData.setSignal(jsonVehicleObj.getString("signal"));
                        Log.d("111126", "2222");
       if(clearflag) {
                       vehicleArrayList.add(vehicleData);
                        vehicleArrayList1.add(vehicleData);
                        Log.d("111127", "2222");

        if (vehicleData.getIginition().equals("Off") && vehicleData.isActive()) {
            vehicleArrayListStopped.add(vehicleData);
            vehicleArrayListActive.add(vehicleData);
        } else if (vehicleData.getIginition().equals("On") && vehicleData.isActive()) {
            vehicleArrayListMoving.add(vehicleData);
            vehicleArrayListActive.add(vehicleData);
        } else if (!vehicleData.isActive()) {
            vehicleArrayListInActive.add(vehicleData);
        }
    }

                        Log.d("vehicleno1111",vehicleData.getVehicleNumber()+" ");
                    }
                    clearflag=false;
                    // JSONObject jsonObject1=new JSONObject(array.get(0).toString());
                    // response=jsonObject1.toString();
                    //Log.d("myresponse",response+" ");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("errorrrr1111", e.toString());
                }
                return response;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);

                txtTotal.setText("Total ("+ vehicleArrayList.size()+")");
                txtMoving.setText("Moving ("+ vehicleArrayListMoving.size()+")");
                txtStopped.setText("Stopped ("+vehicleArrayListStopped.size()+")");
                // txtAlerts.setText(jsonObject.getString("TotalActive"));
                txtInactive.setText("InActive (" + vehicleArrayListInActive.size() + ")");

                    if(!DashboardActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
                    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }



        }

    }
```

//dashboard activty calls vehicle service every 30 seconds & storing in different arraylist like moving, stopped etc. i am using that arraraylist & settting adapter & calling notifydatasetchanged (every 10 sec) in vehicle activity

```
VehicleList class

public class VehicleList extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


    Runnable r;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask myTimerTask;
   ListView lstVehicle;
    EditText searchBox;
   static String status;
   // Context context;
   VehicleListActivityFinal vehicleListActivityFinal;
    ImageView img;
    static UserData userData;
    int accid,timdiff,mile;
    String userid,acctype;
   VehicleListAdapter listAdapter;
    final Handler handler =new Handler() ;

    VehicleListActivityFinal vehiclefinal;

    }*/



    public VehicleList() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("oncreate..", "oncreate..");
          }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vehicle_list, container, false);
        //vehicleArrayList =new ArrayList<VehicleData>();
        lstVehicle =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_listview);
       // lstVehicle.requestFocus();
        img=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.Imgnodata);
        Log.d("createview", "createview");
        if (getArguments() != null) {
          //  Bundle bundle=getArguments();
            userid=getArguments().getString("UserID");
            acctype=getArguments().getString("acctype");
            timdiff=getArguments().getInt("TimeDiff");
            status=getArguments().getString("status");

            Log.d("arg1111",userid+" ");
            Log.d("arg11112",timdiff+" ");
                  }
        else
        {
            Log.d("insidenull","nullnull");
        }
        return  view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        vehicleListActivityFinal=(VehicleListActivityFinal)getActivity();
        searchBox=(EditText)vehicleListActivityFinal.findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
        Log.d("onactivitycrated..", "activitycreated...");

        if(savedInstanceState==null) {

            if (CheckInternet.isConnectionAvailable(vehicleListActivityFinal)) {

                  getVehicleData();
                updateVehicleData();

            } else {
                CheckInternet.showNoInternet(vehicleListActivityFinal);
            }


        }

        Log.d("testtest", vehicleListActivityFinal.test + " ");

        lstVehicle.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                try {

                    VehicleData vehicleData = (VehicleData) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(vehicleListActivityFinal, VehicleDetailActivity.class);

 intent.putExtra("vehicleData1", vehicleData);
                  intent.putExtra("acctype", acctype);

                    // intent.putExtra()
                    startActivity(intent);
                    vehicleListActivityFinal.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_in, R.anim.push_out);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(vehicleListActivityFinal,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        searchText();

      //  updateVehicleData();
      // setRetainInstance(true);

    }
```

//method which calls notifydatasetchanged every 10 seconds on vehicle activity

```
public void updateVehicleData(){

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                vehicleListActivityFinal.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //  getVehicleData();
                            img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            lstVehicle.invalidate();
                            if (lstVehicle.getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
                                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(vehicleListActivityFinal, "empty list..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(vehicleListActivityFinal, "Refreshing Data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000);

}
```

method which sets adapter of vehicle on vehicle activity

```
    public void getVehicleData(){

       // lstVehicle.requestFocus();
        if(VehicleListActivityFinal.movingStatus.equals("moving")) {
            listAdapter = new VehicleListAdapter(vehicleListActivityFinal, DashboardActivity.vehicleArrayListMoving,vehicleListActivityFinal);
          //  Log.d("adapterempty", listAdapter.isEmpty()+" ");
            lstVehicle.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            //listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(VehicleListActivityFinal.movingStatus.equals("total")){
            listAdapter = new VehicleListAdapter(vehicleListActivityFinal,  DashboardActivity.vehicleArrayList1,vehicleListActivityFinal);
            lstVehicle.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            //listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(VehicleListActivityFinal.movingStatus.equals("inactive")){
            listAdapter = new VehicleListAdapter(vehicleListActivityFinal, DashboardActivity.vehicleArrayListInActive,vehicleListActivityFinal);
            lstVehicle.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            //listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(VehicleListActivityFinal.movingStatus.equals("stopped")){
           listAdapter = new VehicleListAdapter(vehicleListActivityFinal, DashboardActivity.vehicleArrayListStopped,vehicleListActivityFinal);
            lstVehicle.setAdapter(listAdapter);
           // listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
        {
           listAdapter = new VehicleListAdapter(vehicleListActivityFinal, DashboardActivity.vehicleArrayList1,vehicleListActivityFinal);
            lstVehicle.setAdapter(listAdapter);
           // listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

       // lstVehicle.invalidate();
        //lstVehicle.requestLayout();



        Log.d("postexecute1111", searchBox.isFocused() + " ");


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        VehicleListActivityFinal.currentFragment="VehicleList";


    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        Log.d("detach1", "detach");

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("onresume", "onresume");


    }


    public void searchText() {

       // lstVehicle.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                Toast.makeText(vehicleListActivityFinal,"beforetextchanged",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s1, int start, int before, int count) {
                listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s1.toString());
                //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ontextchanged",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //lstVehicle.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                //listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"afterrtextchanged",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: lots of code but what is your question actually?

Comment: private class vehicle extends AsyncTask ---it is used for updating vehicle details & stores in arraylist &

Comment: and? i still dont see any question...

Comment: private class vehicle extends AsyncTask ---it is used for updating vehicle details in every 30 sec (in dashboard activity) & stores in arraylist & another class with methods getVehicleData() (used in second activity vehicle list ) used for setadapter , gettting data from arraylist & finally calling updateVehicleData() to call notifydatasetchanged in every 10seconds ...........but i am gettting error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification."

Comment: so update your question and write your error there, otherwise nobody will follow your comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed