# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.

Tags: android

I would like to put a large number of add delete calculation work on the worker thread, notifyDataSetChanged work on the ui thread. On the basis of it to avoid the java.lang.IllegalStateException. Exception as follows: 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.

code shorthand such as:

```
new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i=0; i<5000; i++){
                    mDatas.add(i);
                }
                mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed

Comment: what is mAcitvity ?

Comment: Also you can try adding data and *notifyDataSetChanged* both inside *UI thread*.

Comment: @jaydroider thanks , I read the question but did not feel the perfect answer.

Comment: @quick learner  it's current activity

Comment: @jaydroider If it is large data will affect the performance.

Comment: did u check if mActivity is null or not ?

Comment: @quick learner  Thank you for pointing out the problem with my code. And I focus on the above problems.

Comment: i posted my answer, if hope it works, Do upvote if its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to overcome with it.

1) Use `AsyncTask` and update your adapter in `onPostExecute()` method.

```
@override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

2) Use `Handler` with `Thread` to register message and in `handleMessage()` update your adapter.

```
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

                  handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();

 Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You may not have read my question, no matter how or thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are adding items to ArrayList in non-UI thread and calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the UI Thread

```
new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for(int i=0; i<5000; i++){
                            mDatas.add(i);
                        }
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: A large number of operations in the UI thread will have performance problems such as UI card Dayton.

Comment: are you calling `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` from any background service ? if its from activity/fragment you don't need the whole runOnUiThread thing

Comment: it's from dialog calling mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Check if mActivity is null or not before calling `runOnUi` thread

```
 new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i=0; i<5000; i++){
                        mDatas.add(i);
                    }
                  if(mActivity!=null){
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                   }
                }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem with my code. And I focus on the above problems.

Comment: sorry, I hope that I can upvote for you, but my honor is less than fifteen.