# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification -Android

Tags: java, android

I have looked through a lot of content online but none of the suggestions work. I have a listview that sometimes work and sometimes crashes my app with the following:

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a
>   notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
>   from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your
>   adapter calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` when its content changes.

I am definitely calling the `notifyDataSetChanged()` (In the `onPostExecute()` of an async task). I have tried as suggested by examples online to run it on the main thread like below:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    CAdapterFilter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

but that did not work either. Still my app will crash at random times. Can anyone shed some light here? Why is it only crashing randomly and not every time. What am I missing?

Comment: do you add items to your adapter on UI or background thread?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() will only get notified when your data is gets changed using add(),delete(),update() methods.

Comment: shall we guess the error ? is your `logcat error` **Irritating ListView exception** ?

Comment: I have a custom adapter where the items are being added in the doInBackground process? Is this the issue? Should it be added onPostExecute?

Comment: @Santanu - You obviously didn't read my question because I am quoting the error.

Comment: [@Christopher Smit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3948544/christopher-smit) [could be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed)

Comment: got it..now post your `doInBackground` method we will fix it !!

Comment: Post your logcat here and what is CAdapterFilter ??? is it class or object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
doInBackground(....) {
 mPseudoList.addAll(fetched_list);
 return xyz;
}

onPostExecute(...) {
 mAdapterList.addAll(mPseudoList);
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Change the `adapter list` reference in `onPostExecute(...)` and then notify the adapter !!

**Note :-**

In `doInBackground` *dont* update the list whose **reference the adapter holds** , instead use a `pseudo-list` and update the adapter reference list in `onPostExecute`

Comment: This is basically the approach I went with and it works so will accept the answer. Thanks.