# Fetch contacts and show simultaneously

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, lazy-loading, contacts

I am fetching contacts and this work is going fine. But I am try to also show the contacts in bunch of 50 which is fetched, i.e. user don't have to wait until all contacts has been fetched.
I try to with Asynctask , And Thread also but when I go to notify the list adapter then error has came.

> "The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive
>   a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
>   from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your
>   adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes"

Comment: where are you fetching your contacts from? how many contacts do you have in total?

Comment: From Android Database. I have 8000 Contacts But i resolved the prob Actually you have to add collection (list) add in UI thread if you notify the list in UI thread this is very awkward for me earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed

Comment: simply use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library - no need for reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update the adapter from the `onProgressUpdate()` method of the AsyncTask. The `onProgressUpdate()` can be invoked by calling the `publishProgress()` from inside your`doInBackground()`. `doInBackground()` runs in the Background Thread, while `onProgressUpdate()` runs in your UI thread.

Comment: No I have something else prob But I resolved this Thanks for Reply Sriram