# ListView with custom adapter scrolls to bottom on first loader restart

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-cursor

I am facing a weird issue here.

In my app, the user needs to restart the loader after updating some preferences `onLoadFinished`, all fine here, the thing is that is I set `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` it scrolls all the way to the bottom of the list.

The weird part is that it only happens once, the first time you restart the loader. All the other times the view remains exactly where it is.

I am notifying the change on UI thread...

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXISTING_EVAL_LOADER, null, ViewActivity.this);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

If I don't call `notifyDataSetChanged();` the app crashes **only on list item click** and I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls
>   notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.

Comment: its better to use async task

Comment: @D.'s Even so, I don't thing that would fix my current issue.

Comment: where do you add your item,post more code.there are a lot of answers to this prb have you checked them?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed

Comment: @D.'s Can't post right now. I am adding my items inside onLoadFinished, inside cursor.moveToFirst to be exact since this activity loads only one row.

Comment: is the ordering of the items `desc`?is the last item the most recently added?

Comment: @D.'s Yes , my content provider's query has "_ID DESC"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
          <do stuff>
    }
}

cursor.close();
```

Comment: Will try it out when I get to my laptop and get back to you

Comment: Will get back to you tonight. Busy schedule and I didn't get the chance to test much.

Comment: @Eminem experienced users such as the OP in this case do not need help with accepting answers. They will mark good answers as accepted without anyone telling them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your `listView` is `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` and last item is selected in `listView` and thus `listView` is scrolling to the selection.

if you do not need selecting items on `listView` use this:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE)
```

or in xml:  `android:choiceMode="none"`

otherwise if you need your selection settings use this after setting adapter in `listView`:

```
listView.clearChoices();
listView.setAdapter(listView.getAdapter());
```

---

**if you want first item be selected** and scrolling to top you can use following code:

```
listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

or

```
listView.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: I do need my selection settings and clearing choices  + re- setting  the adapter didn't change anything.

Comment: @Alin what about using `listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView()` OR `listView.setSelection(0)` did you test it?

Comment: @Alin maybe this one helps `if(listView.getChildAt(0) != null)  listView.getChildAt(0).requestFocus()`